# rabbitmq seems to crash on startup

Tags: mac-osx, rabbitmq, brew

I used brew to install rabbitmq.

However, it seems to be unable to start properly.

This is what happens:

```
Tom@MacOS:/opt/homebrew/var/log/rabbitmq % brew services start rabbitmq                                 
==> Successfully started `rabbitmq` (label: homebrew.mxcl.rabbitmq)
Tom@MacOS:/opt/homebrew/var/log/rabbitmq % ls
std_error.log  std_out.log
Tom@MacOS:/opt/homebrew/var/log/rabbitmq % cat std_error.log 

BOOT FAILED
===========
Error during startup: {error,failed_to_initialize_feature_flags_registry}

Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,rabbit,{failed_to_initialize_feature_flags_registry,{rabbit,start,[normal,[]]}}})

Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...%                                                                                                                                                                                                   Tom@MacOS:/opt/homebrew/var/log/rabbitmq % cat std_out.log 
2023-12-07 20:12:37.275943+01:00 [error] <0.234.0> Feature flags: `stream_single_active_consumer`: required feature flag not enabled! It must be enabled before upgrading RabbitMQ.
2023-12-07 20:12:37.279678+01:00 [error] <0.234.0> Failed to initialize feature flags registry: {disabled_required_feature_flag,
2023-12-07 20:12:37.279678+01:00 [error] <0.234.0>                                               stream_single_active_consumer}
2023-12-07 20:12:37.282992+01:00 [error] <0.234.0> 
2023-12-07 20:12:37.282992+01:00 [error] <0.234.0> BOOT FAILED
2023-12-07 20:12:37.282992+01:00 [error] <0.234.0> ===========
2023-12-07 20:12:37.282992+01:00 [error] <0.234.0> Error during startup: {error,failed_to_initialize_feature_flags_registry}
2023-12-07 20:12:37.282992+01:00 [error] <0.234.0> 
2023-12-07 20:12:38.324368+01:00 [error] <0.233.0>   crasher:
2023-12-07 20:12:38.324368+01:00 [error] <0.233.0>     initial call: application_master:init/4
2023-12-07 20:12:38.324368+01:00 [error] <0.233.0>     pid: <0.233.0>
2023-12-07 20:12:38.324368+01:00 [error] <0.233.0>     registered_name: []
2023-12-07 20:12:38.324368+01:00 [error] <0.233.0>     exception exit: {failed_to_initialize_feature_flags_registry,
2023-12-07 20:12:38.324368+01:00 [error] <0.233.0>                         {rabbit,start,[normal,[]]}}
2023-12-07 20:12:38.324368+01:00 [error] <0.233.0>       in function  application_master:init/4 (application_master.erl, line 142)
2023-12-07 20:12:38.324368+01:00 [error] <0.233.0>     ancestors: [<0.232.0>]
2023-12-07 20:12:38.324368+01:00 [error] <0.233.0>     message_queue_len: 1
2023-12-07 20:12:38.324368+01:00 [error] <0.233.0>     messages: [{'EXIT',<0.234.0>,normal}]
2023-12-07 20:12:38.324368+01:00 [error] <0.233.0>     links: [<0.232.0>,<0.44.0>]
2023-12-07 20:12:38.324368+01:00 [error] <0.233.0>     dictionary: []
2023-12-07 20:12:38.324368+01:00 [error] <0.233.0>     trap_exit: true
2023-12-07 20:12:38.324368+01:00 [error] <0.233.0>     status: running
2023-12-07 20:12:38.324368+01:00 [error] <0.233.0>     heap_size: 376
2023-12-07 20:12:38.324368+01:00 [error] <0.233.0>     stack_size: 28
2023-12-07 20:12:38.324368+01:00 [error] <0.233.0>     reductions: 173
2023-12-07 20:12:38.324368+01:00 [error] <0.233.0>   neighbours:
2023-12-07 20:12:38.324368+01:00 [error] <0.233.0> 
2023-12-07 20:12:38.342452+01:00 [notice] <0.44.0> Application rabbit exited with reason: {failed_to_initialize_feature_flags_registry,{rabbit,start,[normal,[]]}}
```

When running `rabbitmqctl status` I get the following output:

```
Error: unable to perform an operation on node 'rabbit@localhost'. Please see diagnostics information and suggestions below.

Most common reasons for this are:

 * Target node is unreachable (e.g. due to hostname resolution, TCP connection or firewall issues)
 * CLI tool fails to authenticate with the server (e.g. due to CLI tool's Erlang cookie not matching that of the server)
 * Target node is not running

In addition to the diagnostics info below:

 * See the CLI, clustering and networking guides on https://rabbitmq.com/documentation.html to learn more
 * Consult server logs on node rabbit@localhost
 * If target node is configured to use long node names, don't forget to use --longnames with CLI tools

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

attempted to contact: [rabbit@localhost]

rabbit@localhost:
  * connected to epmd (port 4369) on localhost
  * epmd reports: node 'rabbit' not running at all
                  no other nodes on localhost
  * suggestion: start the node

Current node details:
 * node name: 'rabbitmqcli-597-rabbit@localhost'
 * effective user's home directory: /Users/Tom
 * Erlang cookie hash: KjL105zkFhCuCRF4xXum7g==
```

I have not idea what is wrong here. Anybody got an idea?